# Woocommerce product columns/rows broken

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Im developing a wordpress woocommerce site and for some reason the product listing is broken. 
Ive tried different plugins and even css but can't seem to fix this positioning problem.. It seems to be working on the last page (i not sure if this is because of the listing have 1 row on the last page)

http://image.prntscr.com/image/83ab691cd2c24cf7bca34ef8f1a69847.png

Problem is happening at the bottom of this page; http://mycompany.com/shop

Could anyone help me with a fix? im out of ideas. 
Thanks

Comment: share some code please

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: What code do you need to see?

Comment: @LBlakemore would you please share your link?

Comment: Problem is happening at the bottom of this page; http://historicmotorsporttransmissions.com/shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change number of products displayed per page in woocommerce by adding the following code in the `functions.php` of your active theme.

```
// Display 8 products per page. Goes in functions.php
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 8;' ), 20 );
```

If you want to change number of products per row in woocommerce then use the following code.

```
// Change number or products per row to 5
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 5; // 5 products per row
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix the problem that im getting as detailed above would just change the total amount of products displayed and not effect the column/row positioning bug. But I will try to see if it fixes anything thank you.

Comment: @LBlakemore have you add above code in your `functions.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a 2c, I had the same issue, battled about 2 hours to find the reason. Changing the Heading padding solved the issue for me. Tried the above and nothing worked. So just in case, someone comes across this, try changing the product padding. Maybe different per theme, but this fixed the horrible gaps for me.

```
.woocommerce .products .product h3, .woocommerce .products .product h2 {
    padding: 0px 0;
}
```